# Redirect old page to new page use htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have new Content Management System which rewrite old static code.

I want to redirect some old page to some new page, for example I want to redirect 3 pages only to 3 new pages:

```
domain.com/oldpage1 => domain.com/new/newpage1
domain.com/oldpage2 => domain.com/new/newpage2
domain.com/oldpage3 => domain.com/new/newpage3
```

how to do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite for stuff like that. Have a look here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

There are many possibilities and the exact commands depend on your link structure, but in principle (assuming that its about redirecting `domain.com/mypage`to `domain.com/new/mypage`) it works like that in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /new [L]
```

**Edit**: Of course you will have to install / activate Apaches mod_rewrite beforehand if its not already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple. Use these 3 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldpage1/?$ /new/newpage1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^oldpage2/?$ /new/newpage2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^oldpage3/?$ /new/newpage3 [L,NC,R=301]
```